# Using items from multiple comboBoxes

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have got few comboBoxes like:

```
final JComboBox listCosN = new JComboBox();
        listCosN.setBounds(289, 261, 36, 20);
        painting.add(listaCosN);
        listCosN.addItem(1);
        listCosN.addItem(2);
        listCosN.addItem(3);

        listCosN.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int choosedCosN = listCosN.getSelectedIndex();
            }
        });
```

And now i want to use those choosed items from all of the comboBoxes. Doing simply
(for ex.)

```
int x = choosedCosN; after "});"
```

doesn't solve anything, because "int x cannot be resolved to a variable". That means choosed items are like local variables? How can i solve this?

Comment: you do realize that choosedCosN is a local variable right ?

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked how can i resolve this and use those variables.

Comment: moving your choosedCosN declaration out of the ActionListener should work..

Comment: The answers to your question and all others that you are gonna face in the next lines of your program are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/